# what and where is the use of package name in a java program?can a single .java file have two classes?

Tags: java

im a noob in java.
i was learning java from vogella.com,there i saw an example having two classes.
can a single .java file have two class names?(i dont think so because file is supposed to have class name)
First class is:

```
package com.vogella.javastarter.exercises1;

class Person {String firstName;
  String lastName;
 int age;

public Person(String a, String b, int value) {
  firstName = a;
  lastName = b;
age = value;
}

public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
  return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
  this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

}

and second class is:

```
package com.vogella.javastarter.exercises1;



 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person("Jim", "Knopf", 21);
    Person p2 = new Person("Jill", "Sanders", 20);
    // Jill gets married to Jim
    // and takes his name
    p2.setLastName("Knopf");
    System.out.println(p2);
  }
}
```

how am i supposed two compile two separate .java files,because the first file lacks main() method.And second file doesnt connect to 'class Person' file.

And the most important thing how functions/methods of class Person get executed when i see a single function call (setLastName() function).
call me stupid but please clear my doubt.

Comment: Please read more about Java this are the basics of Java

Comment: Just buy and then read this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Java-The-Complete-Reference-Series/dp/0071808558)...

Answer (score 0):

> how am i supposed two compile two separate .java files,because the first file lacks main() method.And second file doesnt connect to 'class Person' file.

If the two files (Person and Main) are in the same folder, they can make references to each other. When compiling, make sure to compile Person first, because Main contains references to it. If you were to compile Main first, it would not have any idea what a "Person" is.

> And the most important thing how functions/methods of class Person get executed when i see a single function call (setLastName() function). call me stupid but please clear my doubt.

I'm not sure what you are asking for here-

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can have many files that rely on each other. For example, your `Person` class has no main method because it cannot be run on its own. That is why the second file exists. In order to run this program, compile both (as Martin M J states, compile `Main.java` first), put them in the same folder, and then run `Main`. Since both files are in the same folder, `Main` can use the methods that all `Person` objects have.

As for the second part of your question, most of the methods in the `Person` class aren't being called. They are just there for completeness. Like your code states, the call to `setLastName("Knopf")` changes the last name of `p2` to `"Knopf"`. In addition, the constructor is called when the `Person` objects are created, giving their names and age.

The only other method called is invisibly called. When the line `System.out.println(p2)` is executed, the `toString()` method of `p2` is called. This caused `println` to print `"Jill Knopf"`, because we've changed her name from `"Sanders"`.

[This section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) of the Java Tutorials explains object-oriented programming more understandably. In fact, those tutorials are a good reference in general.